# How can I decrease the space between the symbol "<" and text?

Tags: fonts, math-mode, spacing, symbols

I use "`0<F<1`" in Latex, however in the pdf it is "`0 < F < 1` ", I want to reduce the space between text and <, just like "`0<F<1`", would someone tell me how to do it?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? This introduces inconsistency in your document.

Answer (score 25):

That's because it's the intended spacing for binary relations. However, by simple braces you can change that, so that they would be treated like ordinary math characters:

```
0{<}F{<}1
```

Answer (score 11):

An alternative in math mode is to use negative spaces defined by `\!`. Each one will backshift characters by 1/6 quad.

Comment: I don't think this is a good idea. If you write $0<F<1$ and the line is full, latex will decrease the space between the "<", "F", "0" and "1" automatically and then the additional `\!` could mess up the equation.

Comment: Oh, it’s a kludge to begin with. The braces are a much better idea, but negative spacing is always good to know about in a pinch.

Comment: +1.This helped me to render the products $SVD$ and $TVB$ nicely when using LNCS style file.

Comment: @CarlChristian +1, e.g. `$\overline{Y\!Z}$`.